# What does $\nabla ^\perp$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

As in the title, I am reading a paper and they use the notation $\nabla ^\perp$ without explaining what it means. Is this standard notation for something? I have not seen it before!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the title or topic of the paper. Is there a first occurrence? Does it deal with Bochner-Laplace operators?

Comment: It is in this paper on page 3:
http://www-m3.ma.tum.de/bornemann/inpainting.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have been able to look up the reference given for the formula, online at (http://www.tecn.upf.es/~mbertalmio/restoration.html), where you find it defined as the rotated or perpendicular gradient,

$$\nabla^\perp=(-\partial_y,\partial_x).$$